# Should I use iOS Distribution or Apple Distribution certificates for a mobile app?

Tags: ios, certificate

It may sound, (let's say) naive, but I don't know which certificate I should use for mobile (iOS) apps.

The obvious option would be iOS Distribution certificate, but on the Apple Distribution certificate, the explanation is:

> ...For use with Xcode 11 or later.

Since I'm using Xcode 11, I'm confused. It feels like the Apple Certificate replaces the iOS certificate when using Xcode 11 and later.

Is that correct? Or should I keep using the iOS Distribution for iOS apps?

Comment: I'm also interesting in it for macOS app.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Looks like Apple Distribution and Apple Development are only supported on Xcode 11 which means you won't be able to use those certificates in Xcode 10 or below.

### Xcode 11 release note:

*Xcode 11 supports the new Apple Development and Apple Distribution certificate types. These certificates support building, running, and distributing apps on any Apple platform. Preexisting iOS and macOS development and distribution certificates continue to work, however, new certificates you create in Xcode 11 use the new types. Previous versions of Xcode don’t support these certificates.*
**source:** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes

Comment: I remember googling this last year too :laugh:

Comment: Does this mean iOS Distribution certificates are deprecated, and we should only use Apple Distribution certificates going forward?

Comment: I think it seems that the Apple Distribution certificates are more generic, not only for iOS. I would use Apple Distribution certificate If I create it today unless you have something old and you are using XCode 10 to develop and sign it, that is a strange case, as normally you are up-to-date  in your MacOS device.

Comment: @alekop yes, you are right. 
Edit: Only after sending I noticed I clicked on an old post.