# Should I use "apple development" or "ios distribution" certificate for a new ios app?

Tags: ios, app-store

This same question is asked here, but it is in regard to xcode version and there is no useful answer:
[Should I use iOS Distribution or Apple Distribution certificates for a mobile app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851673/should-i-use-ios-distribution-or-apple-distribution-certificates-for-a-mobile-ap)

A 3rd party is building an ios app for us.  They want the provisioning profile etc. for the app store submission.   I need to first create the certificate. There are 7 options. The two which look the most likely are:

1. Apple Distribution: Sign your apps for submission to the App Store or for Ad Hoc distribution. For use with Xcode 11 or later
2. iOS Distribution (App Store and Ad Hoc): Sign your iOS app for submission to the App Store or for Ad Hoc distribution.

I have no idea which I should chose. Is 1 for ios apps, or only for mac apps?  Its not clear.  IS one a newer version of the other?  In which case which?   1. Mentions xcode 11.  2 does not.  Does this mean that 2 is for xcode 10 and below?  or perhaps its universal?  Stangely, "apple development" cert does say for ios, but "apple distribution" cert does not.

This is very unclear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both should work. Option 2 is the "older" one for iOS-only apps. Option 1 is the "newer" one for iOS and Mac apps (Catalyst).